# When a list boxes hover , the right side content box changes but sometimes they show in 2 content boxes

Tags: jquery, hide, show

If I hover biochemistry box ,that biochemistry content visible in right side corner. if I hover over cytopathology the biochemistry content will smoothly disappear and the cytopathology content will appear... and so on. but Sometimes the biochemistry and cytopathology content visible in same time.

```js
$(".nav-link").hover(function() {
  $(this).tab("show")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#first" class="nav-link" id="first-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria- controls="first" aria-selected="false">
      <h3>Biochemistry</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#second" class="nav-link" id="second-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria- controls="second" aria-selected="false">
      <h3>Cytopathology</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="first" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="first-tab">
    <h2>Biochemistry</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab aliquid veritatis commodi quia architecto vero ullam sequi sunt temporibus at cumque adipisci dolor laudantium dolorum, liberoharum similique aliquam vitae!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="second" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="second-tab">
    <h2>Cytopathology</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab aliquid veritatis commodi quia architecto vero ullam sequi sunt temporibus at cumque adipisci dolor laudantium dolorum, liberoharum similique aliquam vitae!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the snippet you create all work, we need to see this "bug". Which browser did you use?

Comment: I am using chrome browser. But I see this issue Mozilla browser also..

Comment: As you can see from snippet all work, the only thing that comes to mind could be the slowness of the connection.

Comment: yes.. I think also @SimoneRossaini.
Thanks for  Your  Contribution.